# Sending "string" and "int" var using send() method in socket

Tags: c++, sockets, send

In My below code I want to send `hit->first` and `*vit` via socket:

```
for (std::map < int, std::vector < std::string > >::iterator hit = three_highest.begin(); hit != three_highest.end(); ++hit) {
    //std::cout << hit->first << ":";

    for (std::vector < std::string >::iterator vit = (*hit).second.begin(); vit != (*hit).second.end(); vit++) {
        std::cout << hit->first << ":";
        std::cout << *vit << "\n";
```

results:

```
2:one
3:ff
3:rr
6:fg
```

i.e. occurrence:word

I want to send this using send() method in socket.
If both would have been `int` or `char` then I can store it into two dimentional array and send that array.
But here that is not the case.

Can some one figure out the way this could be sent using single `send()` in socket?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pack your message up into a string via a `stringstream`, and send the message (prefixed by the string length). The other end would read the string length, then read that many bytes into a string. This string could then be fed into a `stringstream` to extract the data.

In pseudo-ish code, the sending could look like:

```
std::ostringstream oss;
for (...) {
    for (...) {
        oss << first << " " << second << "\n";
    }
}
std::vector<char> v(oss.str().c_str(), oss.str().c_str() + oss.str().size());
uint32_t len = v.size();
iovec iv[2] = { { &len, sizeof(len) }, { &v[0], len } };
writev(sock, iv, 2);
```

The receive code could look like:

```
uint32_t len;
recv(sock, &len, sizeof(len), 0);
std::vector<char> v(len + 1);
recv(sock, &v[0], len, 0);
v[len] = '\0';
std::string s(&v[0]);
std::istringstream iss(s);
for (;;) {
    for (;;) {
        iss >> first >> second;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, do I need to declare `iovec`or what you did will work directly? I did not understand `iovec iv[2] = { { &len, sizeof(len) }, { &v[0], len } };`. Sorry but I was not knowing `iovec` before!

Comment: thanks, it says `The writev() system call works just like write(2) except that multiple buffers are written out. `. It words same as send() call in socket?

Answer (score 2):

Why not define a data structure that holds an int and a char array (you will have to know the max value to define the char array). Next, you can pass an array of this data structure. Alternatively and perhaps more compact, you can use LV (Length Value format). THus, you can have 5:2:one::4:3:ff, that is num_of_char in occurance:word followed by the actual occurance:word. You can build this message and send it in one send() call.

Comment: Thanks: But `5:2:one::4:3:ff, that is num_of_char in occurance:word` I could not understand. Rather num_of_char I want to send occurrence i.e. number of times that words occurred!

Comment: It is a compact way to send info and stores each occurance:value as a set. Basically, count the number of characters that would be taken up by the number of occurance, the ":", and the actual string. Then add that at the front. This forms one set. This way, when the other side gets this message, it would read the value till it hits the first ":" and know how much of characters need to be read for this set. Thus, "5:2:one" would mean that there are 5 chars and so the receiver can read "2:one:" from this. After that, it can look at the next LV set.

Comment: I think it would be very painful for me. Because then I want to insert occurrence and word separately in the sql data. Do you think the way you described would help me further?

Comment: So, is the receiving socket inserting this as a SQL data. Basically, is it getting message from the sending socket and then calling SQL? If that is the case, then I would just use an array of a DS that holds int and a char. That would be simpler.

Comment: I am executing receiving socket from php file. using shell_exec() function. The result I get in receiving socket I fetch in PHP page and then insert it into database. So array at receiving socket would make me convenient to work!

Comment: Can you please suggest any other data structure here?

Comment: If you are using PHP, then you could consider using JSON to encode the array, send it, and then on the other side decode JSON, get the array, and run SQL statements. Here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: At php side I can handle it. But right now issue is how to send it at receiving end in form of array through send()?

Comment: Well, there are libraries for JSON with C++. If this is a piece that is being used heavily in your application, then investing JSON/C++ might be worth it since the other side is PHP and not C++: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016503/what-is-the-popular-json-c-library